# Where to learn about 'Collective Intelligence'?

Tags: computer-science, collective-intelligence

Which are the good resources for research in **Collective Intelligence** ?.

I am a Software Developer,for a year now and I am basically working in Java and Flex platforms. I want to now apply for a PHD in 'Collective Intelligence', to make my application stronger I want to read thoroughly about it before applying.

**I just need some good tutorials / blogs before dipping into the complexities.... Thanks!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Collective Intelligence is a very broad term. You might have to come down and pick an ideal one of choice.
I have done some bit in Semantic Web which is a collective intelligence science. There are tonnes of materials available online.
These are some of the informations which might help you out...

Some links:
[Semantic Web on Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288897/how-to-start-learning-semantic-web)

Reference Docs

1. SPARQL - http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/ RDF -
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax/ Semantic Web W3C -
3. http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Semantic.html An Introduction to Tim
4. Berners Lee’s Semantic Web -
5. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-tim-berners-lees-semantic-web/5552998

Development Tools

1. Jena - http://jena.apache.org/ Pellet: Another Own 2 Reasoner for
2. Java. This has better reviews than Jena.
3. [Pellet Dev tool for Semantic Web](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/)

Answer (score 2):

Although wikipedia never can be trusted, the articles wikipedia links to, often can. You should look at the [wikipedia page about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intelligence), where the best of the links might be [MIT Handbook of Collective Intelligence](http://scripts.mit.edu/~cci/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Its a huge topic, so i doubt you will get accepted wanting to write a PhD on 'Collective Intelligence' alone, but rather a subset of Collective Intelligence, like "What can Collective Intelligence tell us about  and how has it changed the way ?"

Answer (score 2):

The book [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/9780596529321/) is a nice starting point. It introduces basic concepts across recommendation, supervised and unsupervised learning, also some additional decision making algorithms etc.

You'd need to find a specific area of interest, as Jan pointed out its a massive area. Check out the [WWW Conference](http://www.www2011india.com/) for a list of related papers.